# How to make sub queries with multiple values

Tags: json, sql-server

I am using SQL Server, need to extract JSON into multiple rowsets from a select query value. Like below

```
select
dms.*,
(SELECT questionid
FROM OPENJSON((select dmsj.responselist from [dbo].[response] as dmsj where dmsj.id=dms.id))
  WITH (
    questionid varchar(200) 'strict $.questionId',
    responsevarchar(200) 'strict $.response',
  ))
from [dbo].[response] as dms
```

That responselist column has JSON string with multiple rows. I want to display the dms table fully with all response in multiple rows. Like in example:

| Name | Id | Questionid | Response |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Rahul | 2200 | 7878 | Submitted |
| Rahul | 2300 | 7879 | Pending |
| Rahul | 2200 | 7880 | In Progress |
| Ram | 2300 | 2999 | Submitted |

The value rahul is in one row of dms but he has multiple questionid, response in dmsj. I need to display the query output like above table. Can anyone suggest me to do this?

Thanks

Comment: How does this JSON look like?

Comment: [{"questionId":"7888","response":"Submitted"},{"questionId":"7889","response":"Pending"},{"questionId":"7880","response":"In progress"}]

Comment: [edit] any clarifications directly into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you simply need one additional `OPENJSON()` call with an `APPLY` operator:

Table:

```
SELECT *
INTO response
FROM (VALUES
   ('Rahul', 2200, '[{"questionId":"7888","response":"Submitted"},{"questionId":"7889","response":"Pending"},{"questionId":"7880","response":"In progress"}]')
) v (name, id, responselist)
```

Statement:

```
SELECT r.name, r.id, j.*
FROM response r
OUTER APPLY OPENJSON(r.responselist) WITH (
   questionid varchar(200) 'strict $.questionId',
   response varchar(200) 'strict $.response'
) j
```

Result:

```
name  id   questionid response
----------------------------------
Rahul 2200 7888       Submitted
Rahul 2200 7889       Pending
Rahul 2200 7880       In progress
```